# jquery re-attach div on pop up window close

Tags: jquery, popupwindow

I'm using  jQuery to open a popup window which works great but I've also have it that the #content div detaches from "parent" page ...

```
$('.newWindow').click(function(ev){

window.open('popout.html','pop out','width=400,height=345');
ev.preventDefault();
$('#content').detach();
return false;

});
```

link used:

```
<a href="popout.html" rel="0" class="newWindow">Pop Out Window</a>
```

How can I "re-attach" that div when pop up window is closed?

I've tried many of the answers I found here on SO but none seem to work.

**Update:**

It seems my browser cached the popup window as when I viewed the source (via right click view source) I noticed any changes I made IE the new  JS code was not there so closed browser and reopened and hey presto code edits where there...

have temporarily gone for:

```
window.onunload = function(){
  window.opener.location.reload();
};
```

which refreshes the parent page on child close but would still prefer a reattach approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var p; // where p may be of global scope

$('.newWindow').click(function(ev){

window.open('popout.html','pop out','width=400,height=345');
ev.preventDefault();
 p = $('#content').detach();
return false;
});
```

//on window close

```
if(p){
 p.appendTo("body");//or where ever you want it to append
 p = null;
}
```

the code has been taken from example given [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary variable to store the div before `detaching`.

```
var content; // temp storage

$('.newWindow').click(function(ev){

     window.open('popout.html','pop out','width=400,height=345');
     ev.preventDefault();
     content = $('#content');
     content.detach();
     return false;
});
```

When you need to reattach this in the DOM again, just use `.appendTo()`

```
content.appendTo($("#whereToReAttach"));
```